# Do Hand Ground Beans Work for a Moka Pot?

Tags: moka, grinder

I'm thinking of buying a hand grinder but can't seem to find enough information to ensure that I'll be able to make good coffee in my Moka pot, i.e., that the size of the grind will be adequate.

Can I make decent coffee in a Moka Pot with beans ground in a hand grinder?

Comment: Which hand grinder? The more expensive ones offer high consistency of fine grinds necessary for portafilter machines, with the moka pots not needing as fine a grind, they are a bit less demanding.

Comment: I haven't selected one yet. The answer below gives me some guidance which is just what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I've used manual grinders for many brew methods, including moka pot, Aeropress, and pour over, and it has worked well with all of them. Make sure to get one with a good range of adjustment for the burrs. Steel vs. ceramic burrs doesn't matter in my experience.